# How do you prove the existence of the addition function without pre-supposing it?

Tags: recursion, peano-axioms

Context: self-study from Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* (revised ed., 2010).

So I have this question, which is exercise 8.4 (a) in Chapter 3 (page 44 of Dover edition).

> Prove that there is a unique function $A(x,y)$ from $\omega \times \omega$ into $\omega$ such that for any natural numbers $x$ and $y$, $A(x,0) = x$ and $A(x, y^+) = A(x, y)^+$. (This is the usual *addition* function. Writing $x + y$ for $A(x, y)$, we have $x + 0 = x$ and $x + y^+ = (x + y)^+$.)

(In the above:

- $\omega$ is the von Neumann construction of natural numbers: $0 \equiv \varnothing$, $n \equiv \{x: x \subsetneqq n\}$
- $n^+$ is the successor function: $n^+ = n \cup \{n\}$, from which the existence of the addition function will then *propter hoc* allow one to identity $n^+$ with $n + 1$. Obviously we can't at this stage talk about $n + 1$ because we haven't defined it quite yet.
  )

From the structure of Smullyan and Fitting, I am led to believe that I ought to be using the following "strengthened" version of the Principle of Recursive Definition (PRD henceforth), which goes:

> For any class $A$ and any element $c$ in $A$ and any function $g(x, y)$ from $\omega \times A$ into $A$, there is a unique function $f$ from $\omega$ into $A$ such that $f(0) = c$ and for any number $n$, $f(n^+) = g(n, f(n))$.

Notwithstanding the fact that reusing $A$ from its definition as a general class to the name of the function we are trying to prove the existence of is confusing, it is difficult to see which of $f$ and $g$ is analogous to the function $A$ we are trying to prove the existence of.

I'm trying all sorts of random stuff.

First I try this:

For any given $x \in \omega$, $f(y)$ can be defined as $A(x, y)$ such that:

$f(0) = A(x, 0) = x + 0 = x$ and $f (y^+) = A(x, f(y)) = A(x, A(x, y))$

but that is obviously completely wrong because it doesn't give the right function, and I'm presupposing the existence of the $A$ I'm trying to establish the existence of. Clearly I'm on the wrong track.

So, suppose we let this $g$ function be defined as: $g(x, y) = \begin{cases} x & : y = 0 \\ g(x, n)^+ & : y = n^+ \end {cases}$

That is, define $g$ to be the function $A$ that we are trying to establish the existence of. In this context, $f$ is the successor mapping itself.

But again, a) that presupposes the existence of $A$, and $b$ it is not clear what $g$ actually is, because it uses $g$ to define itself

According to the rubric of the PRD above, "for ... any function $g(x, y)$ from $\omega \times A$ into $A$". In this case of course (the class) $A$ is identified with $\omega$, so it's $g(x, y)$ from $\omega \times \omega$ into $\omega$ that we want to start with.

It is of course straightforward but tedious to set up an inductive argument based on the PRD, but that is effectively "proving PRD all over again" and such seems futile.

Comment: Basically, the PDR above define a one-argument function $f$; to use it for $+$, you have to define a "family" of functions $f_m$ so defined: $f_m(0)=m$ [this amounts to: $m+0=m$] and $f_m(n^+)=f_m(n)^+$ [this corresponds to: $m+n^+=(m+n)^+$]. By PDR, $f_m: \omega \to \omega$ exists for every $m \in \omega$.

Comment: Now define $+ = \{ ((m,n), f_m(n)) \mid (m,n) \in \omega \times \omega \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But what I don't understand is: the PDR works by proving the existence of a function $f$ which arises as a consequence of having already defined $g$. It does not say: "If you define a function $f$, then you can find a function $g$ that ..." etc. And even so, having defined that $f$, I'm having difficulty identifying your definition of $+$ with a $g$ defined as the PDR. Sorry, but I'm still puzzled. I get that it's probably trivial, but I don't get it.

Comment: "there is a unique function f from ω into A such that f(0)=c and for any number n, f(n+)=g(n,f(n))." We define a function $f_m$ **for every** $m$ using that definition: $m$ as $c$ and $^+$ (the *successor* function) as $g$: $f_m(n^+)=g(n,f_m(n))=(f_m(n))^+$

Comment: Ok, my proposal is based on Th.8.1, page 40.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But that means we are defining $f$ first, and from that we are defining $g$. (I know the definition of PRD is theorem 8.1 on page 40, that's where I got it from.) I am having difficulty seeing how $g$ is defined without defining $f$ first. S&F imply that $g$ comes first, and $f$ is then shown to exist once we have defined $g$. Seriously, I don't understand what is being done. Repeating what it says in the book isn't helping me, I'm afraid. I've read the book, it's in front of me now.

Answer (score 2):

> Prove that there is a unique function $A(x,y)$…such that for any natural numbers $x$ and $y$, $A(x,0)=x$ and $A(x,y^+)=A(x,y)^+$.

Fix $x_0\in\omega$.  We want to apply the PRD to the as-yet-undefined function $y\mapsto A(x_0,y)$, so recall the PRD:

> …there is a unique function $f$…such that $f(0)=c$ and for any number $n$, $f(n^+)=g(n,f(n))$.

Comparing the left-hand sides, we see that we want $f(y)=A(x_0,y)$.  The PRD then should produce $$f(0)=A(x_0,0)=x_0$$ and $$g(n,A(x_0,n))=g(n,f(n))=f(n^+)=A(x_0,n^+)$$  Comparing to our original claim, we see that we want to choose $c=x_0$ and $g(n,z)=z^+$.

Then the PRD implies that there is a unique function $y\mapsto A(x_0,y)$ satisfying the desired conditions at $x_0$.

Since we did not rely on the value of $x_0$ in this proof, we can generalize to arbitrary values; for each $x$, there is a unique function $y\mapsto A(x,y)$ satisfying the desired conditions at $x$.  But if there exists a class $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for all $p\in X$, there is a unique object $c_p\in\mathcal{C}$, then there exists a unique function $X\to\mathcal{C}$, viz. $p\mapsto c_p$.

Thus there exists a unique function $x\mapsto(y\mapsto A(x,y))\in\omega\to(\omega\to\omega)$; undoing the [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), $A\in\omega^2\to\omega$.  But there is still a technical detail left in the quantifiers of our desired conditions.

Notice that our desired conditions do not place any "compatibility" relations on $A(x,y)$ as we vary $x$; in the first condition $A(x,0)$ appears once, and in the second, $A(x,y^+)$ and $A(x,y)$ have the same "$x$-argument".  So if

> for every $x$, $A$ satisfies the desired conditions at $x$,

holds, then

> $A$ satisfies the desired conditions at every $x$

because those conditions are the same thing across the two statements.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the concept of "there is a unique function $y \mapsto A(x_0, y)$..." Is $y$ a function now? Or is $y \mapsto A(x_0, y)$ just a way of specifying some function anonymously? And then $\omega \to (\omega \to \omega)$? I'm lost. Yes, I can look up currying, but the wikipedia article needs intelligence, and I'm thick.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Just specifying a function anonymously; an equivalent notation would be $A(x_0,(\cdot))$.  The idea is that we can build our 2-variable function out of single variable functions, one function for each value of $x$.

Comment: That's an infinite process though. Does that mean to be rigorous I have to set up an induction argument? The whole point of doing this exercise (that is, to use the PRD) is so I don't have to use an induction argument. As this is a fairly early exercise in S&F when he is still at the basics, I'm fairly sure there must be a way of reaching the answer without going into all this post-doctorate stuff.

Comment: @PrimeMover: No, that process is not "infinite", because it can be parallelized.  Induction is for processes of arbitrary length _that depend on previous steps_; here each function $A(x_0,\cdot)$ is independent of other choices of $x_0$, and so only takes one "step".

Comment: Okay, thanks. Going to have to take your word for it until I figure out what's going on here. Might end up raising another question in the end.

Comment: @PrimeMover: Please do ask another question here, when you figure out what the difficulty is.  I can tell that (1) you still are confused and (2) I'm not good enough at explaining this to fix the residual confusion.  But someone else probably is good enough!

Comment: Despite the fact that I have not been able to get an answer that I was after, I have had to award you the bounty.